# Set post action in Axios

Tags: axios

How do I set the post action in a axios post request? In JQuery I do it like so:

```
jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, 
  {
      'action': 'add_foobar',
      'data':   'foobarid'
  }, 
  function(response){
      alert('The server responded: ' + response);
  }
);
```

This does not work for axios...

```
axios.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, {
    action: 'add_foobar',
    data: {
      foobarid: 'foobarid'
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert('Message successfully sent')
  })
  .catch(e => {
    alert('Failed to send message' + e.message)
  })
```

I get a `400` error back. Any idea how to set the post `action`?

Comment: can you share the full 400 response please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all some more data will be helpful.

Secondly, there is no need to explicitly send data separately.
th

```
axios.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, {
      'action': 'add_foobar',
      'data':   'foobarid'
  }
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert('Message successfully sent')
  })
  .catch(e => {
    alert('Failed to send message' + e.message)
  })
```